# NameError: uninitialized constant Game

Tags: ruby

I have a file Word.rb

```
class Word

attr_accessor :word, :letters

    def initialize (word)
        #@word = word
        @letters = word.split('').map{|letter| {:letter => letter, :hidden => true} }
    end

end
```

and another file Game.rb, which will use Word.rb

```
require_relative ('./Word.rb') 
require 'pry'

class Game 

attr_accessor :guesses, :guessed_letters, :words, :current_word

    def initialize (words)
        @guesses = 0
        @guessed_letters = []
        @words = words
        @current_word = current_word
    end
end
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> NameError: uninitialized constant Game

When I try to create a instance of Game like this:

```
game = Game.new(['hello', 'sunshine', 'chipmunk', 'twitch'])
```

I just am not sure what I am doing wrong since I am requiring the `Word.rb` file that `Game.rb` will need. All files are on the same level, nothing is in a subdirectory. Interestingly, I do not get this error once I comment the `require_relative` line out (but of course, I need that file required). I have also tried not using `require_relative` and simply using `require` as well as a couple other varieties: parens/no parens, file extension/no file extension, etc. How do I properly require this file? I also have a lovely and robust array of words sitting in another file that I would like to require to be used and passed into `Game.new()`.

Comment: where are you putting the game = Game.new, in which file?, the reason I ask is that I cannot replicate your problem .

Comment: right now I am just running this (all commands) in terminal, so the game = Game.new() was created in terminal as well

Comment: are you requiring Game.rb in your REPL (IRB/PRY) session?

Comment: oh wow, I have to require it manually in terminal? I didn't realize that - I will try that, thanks!

Comment: Well I just pasted   ` require_relative ('./Word.rb')  `   in my terminal and it returned   ` false `   and I got the same error as before. Is there a different way this needs to be required in terminal? I have never done this before

Comment: yes, by default there is no autoloading. So if you want data that is stored in another file you need to require it (require_relative 'Game') should do what you want..

Comment: awesome, I will give it another whirl

Comment: Sweet! That did the trick, thank you so much!!

Comment: Also most rubyists tend to stick with lower case filenames, since depending upon the case sensitivity of your filesystem you can run into issues (Word.rb and word.rb not being the same file, etc..)

Comment: I suspected that the capital in the file name may be wrong, so thank you for pointing that out as well :) I will change it... if you recreate your answer as an actual answer I'd be happy to mark it!

Comment: Uh oh, I admit I just copied and pasted your (require_relative 'Game') into terminal and off I went...but I just realized that what i really wanted was (require_relative 'Word') since I am IN Game already, and need access to Word...so when I ran (require_relative 'Word') PRY returned a `false` and I got this error :  NoMethodError: undefined method `try' for "s":String

Comment: where try() is a method defined in the Word.rb file ....... any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84235/discussion-between-doon-and-holymoly).

Comment: Your Holiness, I'm confused. I find no problem with `Game.new`. Any problem you have certainly has nothing to do with the class `Word`, as Game#initialize makes no reference to that class.  Also, why do you have the arguments `guesses` and `guessed_letters`, since they are not referenced in `initialzied`?

Answer (score 0):

Look What I did

```
$ mkdir test
$ cd test
$ gedit Word.rb
# and copied your content and saved
$ gedit Game.rb
# and copied you content and saved
$ irb
```

After IRB session run I did following

```
2.1.1 :001 > game = Game.new(['asd'])
NameError: uninitialized constant Game
    from (irb):1
    from /home/shiva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.1 :002 > require 'game'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- game

2.1.1 :004 > require 'Game.rb'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- Game.rb

2.1.1 :005 > require './Game.rb'
 => true 
2.1.1 :006 > game = Game.new(['shiva', 'bhusal'])
 => #<Game:0x00000003085428 @guesses=0, @guessed_letters=[], @words=["shiva", "bhusal"], @current_word=nil> 
2.1.1 :007 >
```

Try like this

Comment: thank you:) one of the other commenters, who did not post his solution as an answer helped me figure it out.